# jQuery/css: Fluid responsive isotope grid with square divs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to figure out if its at all possible to have square divs with a fluid isotope layout. I have a 4 column grid, each div being 24% width of the container, but I want these divs to be perfect squares, I can't work out how to achieve this.
Here's a working jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RJZu6/8/ 
jQuery:

```
var $container = $("#main-grid");

var size = function () {
    $container.isotope({
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: $container.width() / 4
        }
    });
}

$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: ".grid-block",
        animationEngine: "jquery",
        sortBy: "random",
        resizable: false,
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: $container.width() / 4
        }
    });

    size();
});

$(window).smartresize(size);
```

css:

```
#main-grid { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid-block { 
    width: 24%; height: 50px; 
    margin-left: 0.25%; margin-right: 0.25%; 
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
    background: no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The fluidity and functionality works fine, just the sizes of the divs I'm having trouble with. Is it at all possible to have perfect square responsive divs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what you have inside as content, you can achieve fluid squares pretty easily using 
`padding-bottom`;

for example

```
width: 50%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 50%;
```

So in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RJZu6/9/) all that I changed was the CSS of `grid-lock`

```
.grid-block { 
    width: 24%;  
    margin-left: 0.25%; margin-right: 0.25%; 
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
    background: no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom:24%;
}
```

[Here's an example of square elements in a page](http://www.fluidsquares.com/)

[Here's more information about the technique.](http://absolide.tumblr.com/post/7317210512/full-css-fluid-squares)

Comment: ah that's perfect, thanks for that! Although there was one thing, I was going to centre some text both vertically and horizontally inside the div. I'm guessing that might be quite difficult?

Comment: @user1374796 I had to do the exact same thing 2 weeks ago. I didn't find an easy way to center vertically and have a fluid square grid. What I ended up doing was centering everything in the square and with jQuery I resized the height of the container. I'll work up a fiddle for you.

Comment: @user1374796 here's the fiddle I promised : http://jsfiddle.net/7MUSB/1/ I'm not sure it works in IE7 but it works everywhere else. Cheers.