# Responsive squares divs

Tags: html, css

I want to have a column with 4 divs with a background-image and fit the 100% of the parent width and give the same to the height to make a square. This is what i have without %:

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 slots" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
</div>
```

And my CSS with `width` and `height` in pixels.

```
.slot {
    background-image: url("img/Inventory_slot_background.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
}
.slots {
    padding: 0;
}
```

I want to give `width: 100%;` and then something like `height: width;`

**Edit:** The problem is that if i use the `padding-bottom: 100%;` if i want to put text or images, the backgrund expands and look like this:

[image]

Comment: Background property: center center nicht help you. Also of you set a width, height will then be assigned automatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/css: Fluid responsive isotope grid with square divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532520/jquery-css-fluid-responsive-isotope-grid-with-square-divs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a pseudo element:

```css
.slot {
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #C9A170;
  background:#EBE6C9;
  border:solid #78624A;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:5px;
  margin:1em;
  }
.slot:before {
  content:'';
  float:left;
  padding:50% 0;
  }
body {
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 slots" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="slot"> anything here</div>
    <div class="slot"> can grow taller than the initial square shape</div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Raxkin you could use inline-block to help alignement http://jsfiddle.net/kjbk64w0/

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish... if you want those boxes to dynamically change size according to their parent div you need javascript for that, can't do with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vertical padding with a percentage for this:

```
.slots {
    width: 150px;
}
.slot {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/26dhhune/

Comment: This is what i tried but because of the padding i cant put nothing on it, as you can see on my edit.