# Making a square div with inheritance or sth? (no js)

Tags: css, height, width

Is there a way to read the width and set a height with the same value ?
I know the trick with viewportheight[vh] and [vm], but it won't work well here.

Comment: Not without script. So what is it you want to accomplish?

Comment: Just wanted to know if there's any way to do it with inheritance or by mirroring paddings of some sort

Comment: @Ori Drori posted a good solution for you.

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449478/responsive-squares-divs/29449834 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by utilizing the fact that in `padding-bottom: 100%` the percentage is percentage of the width, and not the height. So setting a pseudo-element with `padding-bottom: 100%` will change the height according to width. The content can be in an absolutely position layer.

(I've added a little hover animation to demonstrate that changing width also changes the height)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

.container:hover {
  width: 150px;
  transition: width 2s;
}

.container::before {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  content: '';
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice :)
something i've been looking for